# "Out of memory" error when div class not found

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with ChromeDriver

```
Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

driver.Get "https://somewebsite.com"

val = driver.FindElementByCss(".some-class-that-does-not-exist-on-this-page").Text

Cells(x, 2).Value = val
```

When my vba code cannot find that class on a page, it throws an

> "out of memory" error 7

even though, my task manager says my memory is only at 29%.

[image]

When I click on help it takes me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/out-of-memory-error-7

I have tried things suggested there:

- Restart Microsoft Windows in enhanced mode.
- Increase virtual memory

  [image]

But the issue still persists. This only happens when it fails to find the div class.

I tried to add an if statement to check if the element exists

```
  If IsObject(driver.FindElementByCss(".some-class-that-does-not-exist-on-this-page")) Then

    val = driver.FindElementByCss(".some-class-that-does-not-exist-on-this-page").Text

    Cells(x, 2).Value = val

  End If
```

But still results in out of memory error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using error handler

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    elem = driver.FindElementByCss(".some-class-that-does-not-exist-on-this-page")
    Cells(x, 2).Value = elem.Text
ErrorHandler:
    Cells(x, 2).Value = "HTML element not found"
    Resume Next
```

Comment: I would just set it to null or empty string. special values are special until the moment they are not (and that moment will come, as you're training the user to get accustomed to seeing those soecial values, and then they start copying them). Not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

remove the ".Text" part. Check if element exists before reading that value.

pseudo:

```
elem = driver.FindElementByCss(".some-class-that-does-not-exist-on-this-page")

if elem is not nothing then
val = elem.Text
// do other stuff
 end if
```

Comment: I tried to, see 2nd code near the end, but that one didn't work.

Comment: when I try your code, I get `invalid use of object` error and highlights "nothing"

Comment: I tried with `if elem is nothing then` `else` `end if` but still get the out of memory error.

Comment: did you remove .Text from the original statement